# Cannot install packages kerndwd, sdwd, and flare packages in R for Caret Machine Learning Requirements

Tags: r, shared-libraries

I'm trying to install these packages as a machine learning requirements for Caret, below is the snippets to try to install it:

```
library(devtools)

==============kerndwd===========================
install.packages("kerndwd")
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/kerndwd/kerndwd_2.0.2.tar.gz")
* installing *source* package 'kerndwd' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gfortran      -O3  -mtune=generic -c  dwd.f90 -o dwd.o
make: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gfortran: Command not found
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:236: dwd.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'kerndwd'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/kerndwd'
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
 (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgnwPZl/filed8c47c72cf0/kerndwd_2.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

==============sdwd==============================
install.packages("sdwd")
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sdwd/sdwd_1.0.3.tar.gz")
* installing *source* package 'sdwd' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gfortran      -O3  -mtune=generic -c  auxiliary.f90 -o auxiliary.o
make: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gfortran: Command not found
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:236: auxiliary.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sdwd'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/sdwd'
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
 (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgnwPZl/filed8c43f746c9/sdwd_1.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

============flare=============================
install.packages("flare")
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/flare/flare_1.6.0.tar.gz")

C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c SFGen.c -o SFGen.o
sh: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: SFGen.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'flare'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/flare'
```

Can anyone clarify me if the package are broken, or is there some way to install it correctly?

(Edit) RTools Path

```
Sys.which("make")
                              make 
"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

Rtools Folder

[image]

(EDIT 2) It seems that I don't install Rtools completely, Reinstalled Rtools properly with Both 32 Bit and 64 Bit ready for building Packages, and then try to reinstall the packages, `kerndwd` and `sdwd` packages already successfully installed, but not with flare packages.. here is the log when I try to install the flare packages

```
> install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/flare/flare_1.6.0.tar.gz")
Downloading package from url: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/flare/flare_1.6.0.tar.gz
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIvesYl\remotes1978219737bd\flare/DESCRIPTION' (5.5s)
-  preparing 'flare':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
√  checking vignette meta-information
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (507ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'flare_1.6.0.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'flare' ...
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c SFGen.c -o SFGen.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c euc_proj.c -o euc_proj.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c mymath.c -o mymath.o
mymath.c: In function 'max_fabs_vc':
mymath.c:141:11: warning: variable 'cnt' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int i,cnt;
           ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c registerDynamicSymbol.c -o registerDynamicSymbol.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c -o slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.o
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_dantzig_ladm_scr':
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:262:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:261:15: warning: variable 'ndata' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int j,k,m,ndata,dim,nlambda,ite1,ite2,ite,max_ite0,max_ite1,max_ite2,num_scr,num_scr1,num_scr2,num_scr1_tmp,num_scr2_tmp,flag,flag1,flag2;
               ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_dantzig_ladm_scr2':
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:411:21: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,rho,zero,eps,eps1,ilambda;
                     ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:410:15: warning: variable 'ndata' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int j,k,m,ndata,dim,nlambda,ite1,ite,max_ite0,max_ite1,num_scr,num_scr1,num_scr1_tmp,flag,flag1;
               ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c -o slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.o
slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c: In function 'slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr':
slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c:236:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,nrholamb;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c -o slim_lasso_ladm_scr.o
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c: In function 'lasso_ladm_scr':
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:12:58: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT;
                                                          ^
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:12:52: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT;
                                                    ^
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_lasso_ladm_scr':
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:183:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c -o slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.o
slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c: In function 'slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr':
slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c:242:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,nrholamb,qrtn;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c -o slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.o
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sqrt_ladm_scr':
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:12:92: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,alp_dif,beta_dif,mu_dif,threshold,tmpd,alp_tild_sq,alp_th,ratio,epsT;
                                                                                            ^
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:12:86: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,alp_dif,beta_dif,mu_dif,threshold,tmpd,alp_tild_sq,alp_th,ratio,epsT;
                                                                                      ^
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_sqrt_ladm_scr':
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:285:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,sqrtn,nrholamb;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slimh.c -o slimh.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c -o sugm_clime_ladm_scr.o
sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sugm_clime_ladm_scr':
sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c:11:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c -o sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.o
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c: In function 'tiger_lasso_ladm_scr':
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:12:58: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT,tau0,tau1,tmp;
                                                          ^
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:12:52: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT,tau0,tau1,tmp;
                                                    ^
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sugm_tiger_ladm_scr':
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:205:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,sqrtn,nrholamb,tau0;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o flare.dll tmp.def SFGen.o euc_proj.o mymath.o registerDynamicSymbol.o slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.o slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.o slim_lasso_ladm_scr.o slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.o slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.o slimh.o sugm_clime_ladm_scr.o sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-flare/00new/flare/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c SFGen.c -o SFGen.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c euc_proj.c -o euc_proj.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c mymath.c -o mymath.o
mymath.c: In function 'max_fabs_vc':
mymath.c:141:11: warning: variable 'cnt' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int i,cnt;
           ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c registerDynamicSymbol.c -o registerDynamicSymbol.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c -o slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.o
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_dantzig_ladm_scr':
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:262:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:261:15: warning: variable 'ndata' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int j,k,m,ndata,dim,nlambda,ite1,ite2,ite,max_ite0,max_ite1,max_ite2,num_scr,num_scr1,num_scr2,num_scr1_tmp,num_scr2_tmp,flag,flag1,flag2;
               ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_dantzig_ladm_scr2':
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:411:21: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,rho,zero,eps,eps1,ilambda;
                     ^
slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.c:410:15: warning: variable 'ndata' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int j,k,m,ndata,dim,nlambda,ite1,ite,max_ite0,max_ite1,num_scr,num_scr1,num_scr1_tmp,flag,flag1;
               ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c -o slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.o
slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c: In function 'slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr':
slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.c:236:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,nrholamb;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c -o slim_lasso_ladm_scr.o
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c: In function 'lasso_ladm_scr':
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:12:58: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT;
                                                          ^
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:12:52: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT;
                                                    ^
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_lasso_ladm_scr':
slim_lasso_ladm_scr.c:183:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c -o slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.o
slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c: In function 'slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr':
slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.c:242:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,nrholamb,qrtn;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c -o slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.o
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sqrt_ladm_scr':
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:12:92: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,alp_dif,beta_dif,mu_dif,threshold,tmpd,alp_tild_sq,alp_th,ratio,epsT;
                                                                                            ^
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:12:86: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,alp_dif,beta_dif,mu_dif,threshold,tmpd,alp_tild_sq,alp_th,ratio,epsT;
                                                                                      ^
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c: In function 'slim_sqrt_ladm_scr':
slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.c:285:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,sqrtn,nrholamb;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c slimh.c -o slimh.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c -o sugm_clime_ladm_scr.o
sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sugm_clime_ladm_scr':
sugm_clime_ladm_scr.c:11:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c -o sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.o
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c: In function 'tiger_lasso_ladm_scr':
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:12:58: warning: variable 'epsT' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT,tau0,tau1,tmp;
                                                          ^
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:12:52: warning: variable 'ratio' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double gap_ext,max_dif,beta_dif,threshold,tmpd,ratio,epsT,tau0,tau1,tmp;
                                                    ^
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c: In function 'sugm_tiger_ladm_scr':
sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.c:205:24: warning: variable 'zero' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     double T,T1,T2,rho,zero,eps,eps1,eps2,ilambda,sqrtn,nrholamb,tau0;
                        ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o flare.dll tmp.def SFGen.o euc_proj.o mymath.o registerDynamicSymbol.o slim_dantzig_ladm_scr.o slim_lad_ladm_scr_btr.o slim_lasso_ladm_scr.o slim_lq_ladm_scr_btr.o slim_sqrt_ladm_scr.o slimh.o sugm_clime_ladm_scr.o sugm_tiger_ladm_scr.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-flare/00new/flare/libs/x64
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'lattice' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'flare'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/flare'
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIvesYl/file1978444e5b5a/flare_1.6.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You don't have Rtools so not `gcc` or `gfortran`.  That means you can't compile from source.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Have Installed RTools, here I update the path of RTools

Comment: That uses `rtools40` yet the error is `make: C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gfortran: Command not found` pointing to *a different directory*.  Maybe you have different R versions installed -- in any even this looks like a local problem at your end.

Comment: Ahh I see now.. from my local, I only have the mingw_64 > bin directory instead of mingw_32 > bin, how can I change the installation path when installing these?

Comment: or is it safe to just change the directory name to mingw_32?

Comment: If I were you I would try to install Rtools ensuring I correctly obtain 32 and 64 bit.  And I would nott randonly muck with directories.

Comment: Okay I will try to ensure installing both, thanks for pointing out the problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217576/discussion-between-jovan-geraldy-candra-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: Pay attention to *error messages*. For `flare` you get bunch of _warnings_ you can ignore, but you missed a very important error: `Error: (converted from warning) package 'lattice' was built under R version 3.6.3`.  Details matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using publicated archived binaries in  https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine, if there contains old package in the time machine, even package flare can be installed using renv installer with format `package@version`

```
install.packages("renv")
renv::install("flare@1.6.0")
```